# Replay option not displaying youtube video in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, youtube

Currently i am trying to play one youtube video in my application UIWebView. On first time playing, the video is playing perfectly and i can able to see and listen both video & audio, but when the video played completely and i select replay option present in video screen,the video is not displaying anything(its just displaying black screen) but i can able to hear audio.

Where i am going wrong, How to fix this problem ?

Tools used : XCode: 4.3.2, iOS :5.1